# Program reads only 4 out of 6 values in the array

Tags: c++

So, people i have tried a program with dynamic allocation of memory.
The program also uses templates. The aim is to find out the smallest value in an array, which the user enters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template < class T >
T checker (T p[]) {

    T hold;
    hold = p[0];

    for (int i = 0; i != sizeof(p); i++ ) { if (p[i] < hold) { hold = p[i]; } }

    return hold;

}


int main() {

    int choice;
    int i = 0;
    cout << "Please enter 5 values either alphabets only or numbers only, i will find out the minimum value of them" << endl;
    cout << "\n1-Characters\n2-Numbers" << endl << endl;

 X: try {

     cout << "Please enter your choice" << endl;
     cin >> choice;
     if (choice != 1 && choice != 2) {throw choice;}

     if (choice == 1) {

        char *a = new char [6];
        cout << "Please enter the values\nHit \"Enter\" or \"Return\" after each entry" << endl;

        while ( i!= 5) {
            cin >> a[i];
            i++;
        }
        i = 0;

        cout << "The smallest value is: " << checker(a) << endl;

     }

     if (choice == 2) {
        int *m = new int [6];
        cout << "Please enter the values\nHit \"Enter\" or \"Return\" after each entry" << endl;

        while ( i!= 5) {
            cin >> m[i];
            i++;
        }
        i = 0;

        cout << "The smallest value is: " << checker(m) << endl;
     }

    }

    catch (int) {

        system("cls");
        cout << "Please enter values out of the given choice" << endl << endl;
        goto X;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

To describe the flow, first the user selects whether "numbers" or "characters", and then after storing the values. The checker function defined compares values until the loop ends and finally returns "hold".

The problem is if you enter 5 values in the array, the function takes account only of the first 4 values in the array.

Comment: Sizeof cannot do magic

Comment: std::vector and std::min_element would be a good alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a problem in the way you're determining the passed array size using `sizeof` operator. `sizeof` way is the right way if and only if you're dealing with arrays not received as parameters. An array sent as a parameter to a function is treated as a pointer, so `sizeof` would return pointer's size, instead of array's. Moreover you're allocating array dynamically so it would be treated as pointer by `sizeof` rather than array in main() too.

Thus inside the `checker(T p[])` method this method doesn't work. You can pass additional size parameter instead, or maybe give a reading to [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/). But for now i think adding additional size parameter would make things work for you:

```
template < class T >
T checker (T p[], size_t sz) {
    T hold;
    hold = p[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < sz; i++ )
      hold = std::min(p[i], hold);

    return hold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

 `for (int i = 0; i != sizeof(p); i++ ) { if (p[i] < hold) { hold = p[i]; } }`

Since `p` is a pointer to a `T`, it has a `sizeof` equal to 4 in 32-bit program or 8  in 64-bit.